# Half Laplacian; (definitions of) and regularity

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have a question regarding the half Laplacian $ (-\Delta )^\frac{1}{2}$ on some smooth bounded domain $ \Omega$ in $R^N$.   I am attempting to clarify some confusion with the various definitions.   Let $ \phi_k(x)$ denote the $L^2$ normalized eigenfunctions of $ -\Delta $ on $ H_0^1(\Omega)$ with eigenvalues $ \lambda_k$ and assume $ \phi_1 >0$.

Example 1.  Note that $ (-\Delta)^\frac{1}{2} \phi_1(x) = \lambda_1^\frac{1}{2} \phi_1(x) $ in $ \Omega$ with zero Dirichlet boundary condition.    Also note that the right hand side is positive and that $ \phi_1$ is smooth on the closure of $ \Omega$.

Example 2.   Let $B$ denote the unit ball in $ R^N$ centered at the origin.  Let $ 0 \le f(x) $ be smooth and compactly supported in say $B_\frac{1}{2}$ and not identically zero.     Now consider the Green function for this operator (with zero Dirichlet boundary conditions) (see for instance " COMPARISON AND REGULARITY RESULTS FOR THE FRACTIONAL
LAPLACIAN VIA SYMMETRIZATION METHODS " page 10, on the archive).   If one writes out $u(x)=\int_{B_\frac{1}{2}} G(x,y) f(y) dy$ and using the explicit form of the Green function they see that $ u$ should behave roughly like square root of the distance to the boundary function ,  when close to the boundary.   So this says that $ u$ can't have a gradient on the boundary.

Questions.  The above examples seem to be at odds with eachother  (one can surely remove this support condition on example 2).  So I guess my question is are the two definitions of for the half laplacian on bounded domains equivalent?   In addition there appears to be a number of papers that give boundary regularity results regarding the fractional laplacian which appear to be at odds with example 2.

Sorry about being very vague.
thanks for any responses.

Comment: I think you would normally define $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ via the spectral theorem, with $-\Delta$ being the Dirichlet Laplacian. Then $T=(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ has the same eigenvectors $\phi_n$ as $-\Delta$, and $T^{-1}\phi_1=\lambda_1^{-1/2}\phi_1$. If you can't reproduce this result from a calculation with the integral kernel of $T^{-1}$, then this just means that you miscalculated somewhere.

Comment: @Christian.  Ya, that is one way to define the half Laplacian.  But there is also the other method where you add an extra dimension and consider a local problem.